# What is maximum rate allowed for a duplicate content in a website?

Tags: blog, content, plagiarism

One of my site is having 23% duplicate content when I analysed my site with siteliner.com. Is this rate is admissible for google? But at the same time I have checked my blog content for duplicates individually with duplichecker.com. I got the green signal saying plagiarism not found. My question is 23% is a threat or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like Google check percentage. Google just check weather particular content is already index or not, and mark the [inception date](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/84014/58259) when they crawl any webpage first time, so if you put the older date(like 2 march 2015) and original content have date like 7 feb 2016, then Google does not think your content is older, instead it will check the inception date, and treat your content very low quality.

You should note check duplicate content on any third party tool, because they does not crawl all the internet webpages like Googlebot crawl, they may have only few indexed webpages and hence some tool report few percentage and some does not. So the best way to check duplicate content is by searching on Google, if Google already index those paragraphs, and if they find same few paragraphs in your site, then your site quality will be consider as low.

And my dear Indian brother, please change your strategy, by using mix duplicate content and [low quality backlinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/109440/58259), you will never rank your site for many years. It will rank for few days, but once Google know your site very well, then you're doom. Why not think about long term/whitehat strategy? It's take some time, but there is peace for a long time.